# Is it possible for an author's first book to be popular?

Tags: publishing

If I were to publish a book, is there any chance for it to become very popular? let's assume is a good book, would it go unnoticed for being an author's first book or does it entirely depend on the book?

Comment: Self-publish or publishing contract?

Comment: Hopefully publishing contract

Comment: I'd say you may be sure if you got yourself a big name with 10th or so book, your first will become popular too :)

Comment: Sometimes an author will self-publish a small run and later get picked up by a major publisher. If it's good, it can succeed - especially today with the Internet to spread the news for free.

Answer (score 5):

J.K. Rowling's debut novel was *[Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher%27s_Stone)*. It was pretty successful.

Answer (score 4):

For some writers, ONLY their first book was popular.  (Some only write one book.  Success can be as crippling as failure.)
Here's a list:

http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/5477.Authors_With_Only_One_Whole_Novel

Although that list isn't counting plays and short stories, which is certainly unfair, I find it telling how many famous writers only wrote one novel.

Answer (score 3):

of course debuts can do well if they're good. Some of it will also depend on marketing and genre, but there's nothing stopping a first novel from being a smash.